# Get all AD object name under specific OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to modify this PowerShell script below to export the OU members (Users and Computers) where the input will be like this:

```
$OUlist = @(
    domain.com/Site-A/OU1 
    domain.com/Site-A/OU2 
    domain.com/Site-B/OU1
    domain.com/Site-B/OU2 
    ... 
    domain.com/Site-Z/OU1 
    domain.com/Site-Z/OU99
)

$targetOUs = $OUList

$users = $targetOUs |ForEach-Object {
  Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_.distinguishedName
  Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $_.distinguishedName
} | Export-CSV "Result.csv" -NTI
```

Result.CSV content:

```
Name, Type
PC1, Computer
Person1, User
PC2, Computer
Person2, User
```

Comment: Your `$OUlist` has a list of canonicalNames and it doesn't have a `$_.distinguishedName` property, can you clarify on that?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue I am having, the input list I have is CanonicalName format, not the DN type :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a list of [CanonicalNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-canonicalname) then you would need to query all OUs to properly get the OU's DistinguishedName to use as `-SearchBase`:

```bash
$map = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties canonicalName |
    Group-Object canonicalName -AsHashTable -AsString

$targetOUs | ForEach-Object {
    # if this `CanonicalName` belongs to an existing OU
    if($map.ContainsKey($_)) {
        $queryParams = @{
            LDAPFilter  = '(objectClass=user)'
            SearchBase  = $map[$_].DistinguishedName
            SearchScope = 'OneLevel' # looking only for immediate objects
        }

        foreach($object in Get-ADObject @queryParams) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Name     = $object.Name
                Type     = $object.ObjectClass
                SourceOU = $_
            }
        }
    }
} | Export-CSV "Result.csv" -NTI
```

Technically, [computer objects are a subclass of the user class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/querying-for-users) hence using the filter `(objectClass=user)` would find both, computers and users in a single query.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer you're missing the `$map` line of my code..

Comment: yes. man, you're right, thanks heaps for this assistance!